# AVL tree left and right rotation C#

Tags: c#, avl-tree

I am trying to implement an AVL tree however when I come to print the tree out, it does nothing. I am thinking that there is something wrong with my left and right rotate implementation.

I have transferred the rotated values between two variables "old" and "new" to make it easier.

```
      private void rotateLeft(ref Node<T> tree)
        {
            if (tree.Right.BalanceFactor > 0)
            {
                rotateRight(ref tree.Right);
            }
            Node<T> oldRoot = tree;
            Node<T> newRoot = tree;

            newRoot.Right = oldRoot;
            oldRoot.Left = newRoot;
            newRoot.Right = oldRoot.Left;

        }

        private void rotateRight(ref Node<T> tree)
        {
            if (tree.Left.BalanceFactor < 0)
            {
                rotateLeft(ref tree.Left);
            }
            Node<T> oldRoot = tree;
            Node<T> newRoot = tree;

            newRoot.Left = oldRoot;
            oldRoot.Right = newRoot;
            newRoot.Left = oldRoot.Right;


        }
```

Heres the Node BalanceFactor

```
class Node<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private T data;
    private int balanceFactor = 0; //added for AVLTree
    public Node<T> Left, Right;

    public int BalanceFactor
    {
        set { balanceFactor = value; }
        get { return balanceFactor; }
    }
```

Insert Item

```
private void insertItem(T item, ref Node<T> tree)
        {
            if (tree == null)
                tree = new Node<T>(item);
            else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) < 0)
                insertItem(item, ref tree.Left);
            else if (item.CompareTo(tree.Data) > 0)
                insertItem(item, ref tree.Right);

            tree.BalanceFactor = Height(tree.Left) - Height(tree.Right);

            if (tree.BalanceFactor <= -2)
                rotateLeft(ref tree);
            if (tree.BalanceFactor >= 2)
                rotateRight(ref tree);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `Node.BalanceFactor`?

Comment: Where is `BalanceFactor` calculated?  From the code you've posted, it looks like `BalanceFactor` will always have the value 0.

Comment: It is calculated within Insert item. 

I'll post the code above.

Comment: One problem you may be having is that the `BalanceFactor` property is getting out of date.  It can change during tree rotations, so setting the property when it is inserted is not enough.  Try changing the `get{}` method of `BalanceFactor` to calculate it each time the property is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code:

```
Node<T> oldRoot = tree;
Node<T> newRoot = tree;

newRoot.Right = oldRoot;
oldRoot.Left = newRoot;
newRoot.Right = oldRoot.Left;
```

and populate `tree` where ever it's possible. … Here it goes:

```
tree.Right = tree;
tree.Left = tree;
tree.Right = tree.Left;
```

I'm *quite* sure this isn't what you were trying to do. Have a look on the AVL balancing algorithm at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void rotateLeft(ref Node<T> tree)
{
    if (tree.Right.BalanceFactor > 0)  //double rotate
        rotateRight(ref tree.Right);

    Node<T> oldRoot = tree;
    Node<T> newRoot = tree.Right;

    oldRoot.Right = newRoot.Left;
    newRoot.Left = oldRoot;

}

private void rotateRight(ref Node<T> tree)
{
    if (tree.Left.BalanceFactor < 0)  //double rotate
        rotateLeft(ref tree.Right);

    Node<T> oldRoot = tree;
    Node<T> newRoot = oldRoot.Left;

    oldRoot.Left = newRoot.Right;
    newRoot.Right = oldRoot;

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).